# How do I select items from a list where no part of an attribute is in a list

Tags: mysql, regex

I've got a table in a MySQL database that I'm trying to output objects from. I have a list of words, and in order for an object to be output from the table, none of the words in the the object's "Name" attribute are allowed to be in the list.

**Table example (MyTable):**

```
ID    Name           Atrib_1    Atrib_2    Atrib_3
1     Hello Kitty    X          10         N
2     Green Chimp    Y          280        Y
3     Chairs Blue    X          14         N
4     Seven Teens    X          342        N
5     Chair Bravo    V          8          Y
```

**List Example:**

```
Kitty, Green, Seven, Chair, Bravo
```

I only want to output objects where no word in the name attribute matches a word in the list - in the above example, the only object output should be the one called "Chairs Blue". I've tried using:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 'Name' NOT LIKE Kitty
```

The issue with this is that I had to manually add a "NOT LIKE" for every word in the list. Also when it gets to the word "Chair", "Chairs Blue" is filtered out because the strings are a partial match.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable m
LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  'kitty' word
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'green'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'seven'
        ) w
ON      m.name RLIKE CONCAT('\\b', w.word, '\\b')
WHERE   w.word IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ...
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Name NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]](Kitty|Green|Seven|Chair|Bravo)[[:>:]]';
```

The funny tokens are word boundaries.  `|` means "or".